# How to insert null for missing column?

Tags: ksh, sql, oracle

I want to write a script that inserts values into a list  of tables as follows.

**Example**:

```
insert into TABLE1
( a,b,c)
select a,b,c from TABLE2;
```

But `TABLE2` does not have column `C`, so I want to insert null for column `C`.

The actual tables I'm using have lot of columns (i.e around 70-100).

Comment: your question can't be answered if you can't specify which tables / columns are missing. Otherwise, you can't know when/where to specify the nulls.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (a, b, c)
SELECT a, b, NULL FROM TABLE2;
```

This will insert the values from columns `a` and `b` in `TABLE2` into the corresponding columns in `TABLE1` while at the same time also inserting `NULL` values into `TABLE1.c`.

Comment: @Thanks for writing. Actually, in real time I would'nt know which columns are missing. Your solution is good for few tables. But is it possible for my script to compare two tables (i.e TABLE1 and TABLE2 ) and then insert null for missing column?

Comment: @mac07 It is a bit unusual to try to do queries against a table without knowing the schema...